# Automation between a google spreadsheet and the downloaded version. Possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel, updates, spreadsheet

I use an iMac and google spreadsheets.
When I want to synchronise my spreadsheets on my drive with the spreadsheets on my imac, I tend to download them. The problem I have is the downloaded spreadsheet is not a live document and the sheet does not get updated if next day I change my google sheet with more cells and different values.
Is there a way at all, to make sure the downloaded version gets updated automatically when I edit the original google spreadsheet?
If so, which is the best way to do so ?
Many thanks
Many thanks
Alex

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would think the best way is to change your work flow to NOT download the file.

Comment: What is the purpose of downloading the google spreadsheet? Just as a backup? Do you download in .xlsx format?

Comment: It seems you're trying to use the "add a service" feature like in Excel? https://support.microsoft.com/en-GB/office/how-to-add-an-account-in-onedrive-31b59063-5a94-4847-b846-c13b9e7635e2

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it is wholly impossible to sync a local file on the file system to Google Drive. Anyway, there are three ways to achieve the desired synchronization:

1. Download Google Drive Desktop and use your desktop applications to edit documents on your google drive. Google Docs' documents use a proprietary file format called **kix**, and therefore, to edit it you're going to have to export your current work to **odt**/**ods**, re-upload it to Drive and edit this file.
2. As one of the comments says, dropping the PC native editor and going full online is an option, too. It is the most painless one, solving all integration and synchronization issue.
3. Write a small script to watch the file in question and pull/push it according to the Google drive API. This is considerably harder than the two above, but is significantly more flexible, and allows you to fully retain your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Transition to work instead with .xlsx files straight in google sheets, rather than its gsheets native format. This way you can edit the .xlsx file online, but also sync the file directly to your computer using the Drive client. There might be some features or compatibility issues using .xlsx files directly in google sheets but most standard features should be fine.

Stepwise guideline:

1. Download the latest gsheets file as .xlsx
2. Install the G-Drive client for mac/windows as appropriate
3. Log-in and configure it to backup / sync folders as required
4. Move the .xlsx file from downloads folder to a G-Drive folder and make sure it has sync'ed the file to the cloud.
5. In your browser, open Google Drive / Sheets and open *the .xlsx version* of your file. Once you are sure this format works for you, delete the old gsheets copy